# flexmix package in R LCA

Tags: r

I want to conduct LCA to predict latent class membership through GAM(generalized additive model)

but I can't find method to handle two or more categorical indicator variable in flexmix package.

I want to use one step method, not three step.

Is it impossible to conduct LCA in flexmix package? not poLCA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.